# prepend directory to all urls mod rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using htaccess on localhost, my htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /website/files/

RewriteRule ^home/?$ home.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^page/?$ page.php  [NC]
```

This url works:

```
http://localhost/website/files/home
```

But when hovering over links on the page they are displayed as:

```
http://localhost/page
```

Instead of:

```
http://localhost/website/files/page
```

All links in the page are set as:

```
<a href="/page">page</a>
```

How can I prepend the directory to all urls in htaccess?

Comment: Where is your .htaccess located?

Comment: in the website directory - website/files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create this .htaccess in the site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule .* website/files/$0 [L]
```

Keep your `website/files/.htaccess` as you've shown in question.

Comment: still the same problem